# Ajax not sending POST var to url

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, html-select

I need to populate related selects with data from the database. The HTML page has a `select` with `id` 'fontes' and a `select` with `id` 'cargos'. The jQuery code right now:

```
$("#fontes").change(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "json_cargos_fonte.php",
    data: ({fonte: $("#fontes").val()}),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(json){
      var options = "";
      $.each(json, function(key, value){
        options += '<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>';
      });
      $("#cargos").html(options);
    }
  });
});
```

And the content of json_cargos_fonte.php:

```
<?php
include ("conexao.php");
header('Content-type: text/json');
$fonte = $_POST['fonte'];
$retorno = array();
$queryCargos = "SELECT * FROM `cargos` WHERE `fonte` = '$fonte' ORDER BY `cargo`";
$resultCargos = $mysqli->query($queryCargos) or trigger_error($mysqli->error."<br>[ $queryCargos]");
while ($row = $resultCargos->fetch_object()) {
    $retorno[] = $row->cargo;
}
echo json_encode($retorno);
?>
```

I already tested putting a manual value instead of '$fonte' and it worked, but passing the value selected in fontes does not work. No option appears, beyond the default option I wrote in the HTML:

```
<select id="cargos" name="cargos" style="min-width: 250px;">
  <option>Selecione um Cargo</option>
</select>
```

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: this: `data: ({fonte: $("#fontes").val()}),` should be  `data: {fonte: $("#fontes").val()},` no? also, post what is in $("#fontes").val()

Comment: So it's REQUIRED to use get when passing parameters to a php file which returns json?

Comment: Hm. I made an alert printing $("#fontes").val() and it add a \ to the end of the string. O.o

Comment: Had to remove that last character and it worked. Gonna answer soon.

Comment: Thanks, Quentin and JS it for the hints. And the other guy who commented about GET.

Comment: Changed the query to: $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM `cargos` WHERE `fonte` = ? ORDER BY `cargo`'); $stmt->bind_param('s', $fonte); $stmt->execute(); $result = $stmt->get_result(); :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alerted value of the select inside the jQuery change function and saw it added a '\' to the end of the string. So, e.g., InfoJobs appeared as InfoJobs\

**Solution:**

```
var fonte = $("#fontes").val();
var fonteNew = fonte.replace("\\","");
```

Then, inside `$.ajax`:

```
type: "GET",
```

and

```
data: {fonte: fonteNew},
```

In the PHP file, changed from POST to GET.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to obtain selected value with jquery, try this

`$("#fontes option:selected").val();`

Answer (score 0):

In order for this line to work:

```
$fonte = $_POST['fonte'];
```

You'll need to serialize your data in your ajax call:

```
data: $.serialize({fonte: $("#fontes").val()}),
```